# Setting state with onClick in render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button in `render()`, and I want it's `onClick()` to set the state. I know you shouldn't be setting the state in `render()` because it causes an infinite loop, so how should I go about this?

```
function initialState(props) {
  return {
    edit: false,
    value: props.value,
  };
}

export default class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = initialState(props);
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.setState({ edit: false, value: this.props.value });
  }

  onClick() {
    this.state.edit ? this.onCancel() : this.setState({ edit: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}> 
        BUTTON
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Updated to show what the code I'm trying now and the warning I'm getting thousands of times:

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a
pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but
can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

warning                            @ warning.js?0260:44
getInternalInstanceReadyForUpdate  @ ReactUpdateQueue.js?fd2c:51
enqueueSetState                    @ ReactUpdateQueue.js?fd2c:192
ReactComponent.setState            @ ReactComponent.js?702a:67
onCancel                           @ mybutton.js?9f63:94
onClick                            @ mybutton.js?9f63:98
render                             @ mybutton.js?
...
```

Comment: It needs to be onClick={this.onClick}, without parentheses, like the answers have been like.

Comment: @Radio- updated and still the same problem :/

Comment: Recompiled/refreshed the page?

Comment: @Radio- yes I have :)

Comment: Are you still getting the same warning and trace? As @radio mentioned, that particular trace would have been caused by putting parentheses after this.onClick in your render method, so if you fixed it and are still getting a warning/error, is it a different message now?

Answer (score 0):

To set the state for your use case you need to set the state somewhere but I wouldn't do it this way. I would bind a function to the `onClick` event.

```
function initialState(props) {
  return {
    edit: false,
    value: props.value,
  };
}

export default class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = initialState(props);
    this.handleButtonClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.setState({ edit: false, value: this.props.value });
  }

  onClick() {
    this.state.edit ? this.onCancel() : this.setState({ edit: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleButtonClick}> 
        BUTTON
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html) for more information

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting those warnings :(

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want to do since the previous answers didn't solve the issue. So if you provide some more information it might get easier.

But here is my take on it:

```
getInitialState() {
    return (
        edit: true
    );
}

handleEdit() {
    this.setState({edit: true});
}

handelCancel() {
    this.setState({edit: false});
}


render() {

    var button = <button onClick={this.handelEdit}>Edit</button>

    if(this.state.edit === true) {
        button = <button onClick={this.handelCancel}>Cancel</button>
    }

  return (
    <div> 
        {button}

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of arrow functions to bind `onBtnClick` and `onCancel` function to the context and see if it solves  your problem.

```
function initialState(props) {
  return {
    edit: false,
    value: props.value,
  };
}

export default class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = initialState(props);
  }

  onCancel = ()=> {
    this.setState({ edit: false, value: this.props.value });
  }

  onBtnClick = () => {
    this.state.edit ? this.onCancel() : this.setState({ edit: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onBtnClick}> 
        BUTTON
      </div>
    );
  }
```